# Running jar file from terminal on linux

Tags: java, linux, jar, terminal, sh

Im trying to run my project jar from terminal.
My project containing SWT library and image folder for the menu.
I wrote on sh file the comman but im getting an error.

My script:

```
java -cp /root/Desktop/applicationFramework/SWT/swtLinux.jar:/root/Desktop/applicationFramework/images/AppMenu.png:/root/Desktop/mainProject.jar boot.Run
```

and the error im getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: i/o error (java.io.FileNotFoundException: images/AppMenu.png (No such file or directory))
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageDataLoader.load(ImageDataLoader.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(ImageData.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:668)
    at view.MenuWindow.initWidgets(MenuWindow.java:52)
    at view.BasicWindow.run(BasicWindow.java:52)
    at view.MenuWindow.start(MenuWindow.java:211)
    at boot.Run.main(Run.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: images/AppMenu.png (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Compatibility.newFileInputStream(Compatibility.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:173)
    ... 7 more
```

what is the correct way to write the script to run my project?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you forgot -jar ?

Comment: well i tried: java -cp /root/Desktop/applicationFramework/SWT/swtLinux.jar:/root/Desktop/applicationFramework/images/AppMenu.png -jar /root/Desktop/mainProject.jar boot.Run

Comment: but still not working

Comment: I think your problem is not your startup script. Is the fact that it cannot find a resource (the image in your case) in your classpath. You should put the images as resources in your project and they will end up in your .jar. If you build your project with Maven, just add them under src/main/resources/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with running the jar like this. But it is failing to find the resources it needs. My understanding is that it is looking for the image from the relative file path, not the class path, try copying the image it is loading images/appMenu. png to the relative directory you are running this from. Or run inside the original app bundle context such that the path will be correct, rather than from the desktop. Moving is preferred because there could be other resources loaded at runtime that are missing.

> cd /root/Desktop/applicationFramework
>
> java -cp SWT/swtLinux.png:/root/Desktop/mainProject.jar boot.Run